# The code after future function builder is not executing

Tags: android, function, flutter, dart, future

I am trying to verify user through firebase otp verification. But my future builder code is not executing.
I am new flutter.
Here the function register user() there is future builder which fetches data from the function getMobile().
But the future builder present in function register user is not executing.
function registeruser() is able to fetch data and return.

````
  Widget func_otpsent(BuildContext context){
    print("su");
    registerUser( context);
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context){
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text("Hello"),
            content: Text("We have sent otp code to your mobile number."),
            actions: [
              FlatButton(
                child: Text("Close"),
                onPressed: (){
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
              )
            ],
          );
        }

    );

  }

  Future registerUser( BuildContext context) async{
    FirebaseAuth _auth= FirebaseAuth.instance;
    try {
      print("hell yea");
      _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    }
    catch(e){
      print(e.toString());
    }
    try{

      Widget build(BuildContext context) =>  FutureBuilder<String>(
        future: getMobile(),
      builder:(BuildContext context,snapshot) {
          print("str");
      if(snapshot.hasData){
        var temp=snapshot.data.toString();
        print(temp);
        print("jk");

        print("hello");
        _auth.verifyPhoneNumber(phoneNumber: snapshot.data, verificationCompleted: null, verificationFailed: null,
            codeSent:(String verificationId, [int forceResendingToken]){
              print("codesent");
              saveOtp(verificationId);
            } ,
            codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: null);

      }
      else if(snapshot.hasError){
        print(snapshot.error);
      }
      return(Text("hello"));
      },

    );}
    catch(e){
      print(e.toString());
    }

  }
  Future<String> getMobile() async{
    SharedPreferences getmob=await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var mobile=await getmob.get("mobile");
    print(mobile);
    return (mobile);
}


} ```

Only important code is show here.
````

Comment: The phoneCodeSent function works? if it is not working so check what is the error on the verficationFailed callback function. there is no need for try/catch inside phoneCodeSent because firebase automatically catches the error.

Comment: Your FutureBuilder needs to be inside *the* build function. You put it into a local function called build that is never called.